# Adjusting Height of a JS Element

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to adjust the height of the code snippet below. Currently, when the popup appears from the JS code below it is concealed by another element on our website, and so I want to increase the height of the code element below so that it is above the other element.

The code is currently on outpostmagazine.com, and you can see that it is impossible for people to click submit because the popup is behind a share bar.

```
<!-- Qualaroo for outpostmagazine.com -->
<!-- Paste this code right after the <body> tag on every page of your site. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _kiq = _kiq || [];
  (function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
    var d = document, f = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0], s = d.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.async = true; s.src = '//s3.amazonaws.com/ki.js/51645/a-r.js'; f.parentNode.insertBefore(s, f);
    }, 1);
  })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting that element margin-bottom with css seems like a good option, although you'll have a gap if the user clicks on the arrow in the sidebar and makes it vertical, like this http://cl.ly/TFqL

Try adding this just before the js code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html div#ki_container {
        margin-bottom: 35px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Ok, so it looks like I am supposed to insert;

  _kiq.push(['options', { bottom: 20 }]);

But I am not sure where to insert it?

Comment: You need to add it to the CSS directly, not as an option. Let me take a look again at the site and will get back to you shortly after.

Comment: As I cannot modify the CSS (I only have an area to apply new lines of code to the entire site) I cannot try this. As such I am forced to try and find a way to make this work by modifying the original code segment.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not an js question. It is a CSS question. I inspected your page with Chrome.

Simply you just add this property to your css for div#ki_container:

```
html div#ki_container { 
margin-bottom: 40px;
(...)
}
```

If you have access to the css of this toolbar(if you are Qualaroo) add it directly there. If not you can override it in your own css files.
It will solve your problem and display your container above the other share buttons and you will be able to click "Send" button.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like I am supposed to insert:

  _kiq.push(['options', { bottom: 20 }]);

But I am not sure where to insert it, can you please instruct me on where to insert this?

Comment: Check both answers, using a js function or a css section to set margin bottom value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, add this section to your script:

```
(function addMarginBottom() {
    var container = document.getElementById('ki_container');
    container.style.marginBottom = '40px';
})();
```

Something like this:

```
<!-- Qualaroo for outpostmagazine.com -->
<!-- Paste this code right after the <body> tag on every page of your site. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _kiq = _kiq || [];
  (function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
    var d = document, f = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0], s = d.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true; s.src = '//s3.amazonaws.com/ki.js/51645/a-r.js'; f.parentNode.insertBefore(s, f);
    }, 1);
 })();



(function addMarginBottom() {
    var container = document.getElementById('ki_container');
    container.style.marginBottom = '40px';
})();

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried the above modification and it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Ask the guys of Qualaroo to add that css attribute value for you.
html div#ki_container { 
margin-bottom: 40px;}

Comment: I can't really do that as it is a free service where they have provided me with the initial code—they told me the answer was to insert 

_kiq.push(['options', { bottom: 20 }]); 

into the code, but I cannot figure out at what point in the initial code to insert it.

Comment: Just guessing , try this:
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _kiq = _kiq || [];
  _kiq.push(['options', { bottom: 20 }]);
  (function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
    var d = document, f = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0], s = d.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.async = true; s.src = '//s3.amazonaws.com/ki.js/51645/a-r.js'; f.parentNode.insertBefore(s, f);
    }, 1);
 })();
</script>

Comment: Does it matter if this is pasted in without proper spacing? I tried pasting the code in after copying it directly from your comment, but it does not seem to be working as the feedback box does not appear at all.